# How to do recursive PostgreSQL query for merging polygons by percent overlap

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm using [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181123/dissolve-overlapping-polygons-according-to-percent-overlap-using-postgis) answer for merging overlapping polygons where they overlap by a certain amount. In the comments there is a mention of doing it recursively and after studying the suggestion its still hard for me to wrap my mind around how to implement it for this example. How could I implement this query recursively?

The query:

```
WITH a AS
(SELECT geometry_id, geometry_geometry::geometry AS geometry_geometry FROM target_geometry),
b AS (select geometry_id, geometry_geometry::geometry AS geometry_geometry FROM target_geometry)
SELECT a.geometry_id, b.geometry_id, ST_Area(a.geometry_geometry::geometry), ST_Area(b.geometry_geometry::geometry)
     , 100*(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geometry_geometry::geometry, b.geometry_geometry::geometry))/LEAST(ST_Area(a.geometry_geometry::geometry), ST_Area(b.geometry_geometry::geometry)))::numeric(5,2)
       as pct_overlap
     , ST_Union(a.geometry_geometry::geometry, b.geometry_geometry::geometry) as new_shape
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.geometry_geometry::geometry && b.geometry_geometry::geometry AND ST_Intersects(a.geometry_geometry::geometry, b.geometry_geometry::geometry)
 WHERE a.geometry_id <> b.geometry_id AND
       30 <= 100*(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geometry_geometry::geometry, b.geometry_geometry::geometry))
                 /LEAST(ST_Area(a.geometry_geometry::geometry), ST_Area(b.geometry_geometry::geometry)))::numeric(5,2)
 
 ;
```